# Looking to make this Active Record Query more performant. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord

Hey so I'm new to active record I have these two map functions here and I'm wondering if there's a better/more performant way to make this below query:

*Right now I'm getting hundreds of lines in my terminal when I execute the query and I'm afraid it could take a lot of memory if a lot of people are loading these converations at the same time?*

**Step 1** is getting all the relevant conversations

**Step 2** is making a conversation hash with all information regarding the sender, recipient and messages linked to that conversation.

**Step 3** is getting all these conversation sorted in the right order which is to sort them from the conversation with the most recent message at the top.

EDIT 1: Rails version 5.0.1

```
 def index
      i = 1
      @messages = []
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      @message = Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", @user.id, @user.id)
      @message.map { |conversation|
        @messages << conversation if Message.where(conversation_id: conversation.id).count > 0
      }



      render json: @messages.map { |conversation|
        {
          date: conversation.messages.last.created_at,
          sender: User.find(conversation.sender_id),
          recipient: User.find(conversation.recipient_id),
          conversation: {
            id: conversation.id,
            messages: Message.where(conversation_id: conversation.id).sort_by{|e| e[:created_at]}.reverse.map {|message| {
              sender: {
                email: User.find(message.user_id).email,
                first_name: User.find(message.user_id).first_name,
                last_name: User.find(message.user_id).last_nam },
              body: message.body,
              created_at: message.created_at
              }
            }
          }}
      }.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:date] }.reverse
 end
```

Comment: Yes this is not efficient because you have multiple N+1 queries getting executed in this action. Focus on the relationships between your models to avoid this. It appears that a particular user will have many conversations through messages. Define this relationship in your user model and you should be able to call `@user.conversations` and ActiveRecord will execute a finite number of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation, touch: true
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations, -> (user) { unscope(where: :user_id).where('conversations.sender_id = ? OR conversations.recipient_id = ?', user.id, user.id) }
end

class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

    # "joins(:messages)" allows only retrieving conversations having at least one message, and does not include conversation with 0 message
    # now ordering by `updated_at: :asc` because `Message belongs_to :conversation, touch: true`, in which Conversation's updated_at will be automatically "touched"/updated whenever the associated Messages are updated/created.
    @conversations = @user.conversations.joins(:messages).order(updated_at: :asc).distinct

    json_response = @conversations.as_json(
      only: [:id, :updated_at],
      include: {
        sender: {
          only: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]
        },
        recipient: {
          only: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email]
        },
        messages: {
          only: [:body, :created_at]
        }
      }
    )

    render json: json_response
  end
end
```

### Example Request

```
Started GET "/conversations?email=foobar@example.com"
```

### Example Response

```
[{
  "id": 2,
  "updated_at": "2018-02-02T11:17:45.376Z",
  "sender": {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Lorem",
    "last_name": "Ipsum",
    "email": "loremipsum@example.com"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar",
    "email": "foobar@example.com"
  },
  "messages": [{
    "body": "Hello there",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T11:17:45.367Z"
  }, {
    "body": "Whatcha doin'?",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T11:17:36.451Z"
  }, {
    "body": "hahaha :)",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T11:03:29.843Z"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "updated_at": "2018-02-02T11:36:14.275Z",
  "sender": {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar",
    "email": "foobar@example.com"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "Ruby",
    "last_name": "Rails",
    "email": "rubyonrails@example.com"
  },
  "messages": [{
    "body": "hello Ruby-on-Rails! :)",
    "created_at": "2018-02-02T11:36:14.267Z"
  }]
}]
```

> You can check out how to use `.as_json` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)
>
> You can check out how to use `touch: true` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch)

*Tested working*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I've been trying to make this work but I'm stuck on the following issue: "uninitialized constant User::ConversationsWithMessage"

Comment: Also the .order method inside the conversation model doesnt seem to be correct syntax. I'm on Rails 5.0 if that could be related. Sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Hugo hi sorry about the incorrect `order` syntax and the `conversations_with_messages`. I've just updated this now. Can you try again. If this doesn't work, I'll try to replicate your scenario so I can verify :)

Comment: Ok so I'm still unable to make the @ conversations query work. The .joins(:messages) transforms @ conversations into an list of messages with each refering to a conversation which isnt working for me. I did manage to use the other parts of your code tho so thanks a lot but I'm still using my own way to retrieve the conversations inside the @ messages variable. Maybe it's a bit misleading that I've used a @ messages name for my var when it should be called @ conversations.

Comment: I'm also still unable to make the  @user.conversations work. I get the no column user on conversation error.

Comment: Oh i see.. hm... I'll try to replicate your scenario. I'll be back in a few minutes.

Comment: @Hugo I just updated my answer. However, I also updated the format of the json response as you could see above, to conform to the rails `as_json` JSON response standard format. Feel free to change the json response format as you wish.